# What is the difference between AWS Transcribe > Streaming Transcription feature and Kinesis Video Streams(For Audio Input) for live streaming audio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-transcribe, amazon-kinesis-agent

Hi My requirement is I have live audio stream as input, say a call between 2 people, now to convert that audio to text on live and pick certain keywords from that extracted text and insert in Database.

As per architecture in *https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-connect-realtime-transcription* Both AWS Kinesis Video Streams service and AWS Transcribe used for live streaming but as per link : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-transcribe-now-supports-real-time-transcriptions/ AWS Transcribe supports live transcription then why in that architecture Kinesis used ?

If any one know, please help me in understanding, Hope Amazon connect can ingest live audio to AWS Transcribe for live transcription.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Kinesis Video Streams is the service that enables streaming voice data from Amazon Connect. Amazon Transcribe can ingest streams from any source for real-time transcription, but the only way to get that real-time data from Amazon Connect is via Kinesis. The [launch announcement for real-time streams](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-connect-adds-real-time-customer-voice-stream/) might help make this more clear:

> With the customer voice stream feature, your customer audio is
>   automatically sent to Amazon Kinesis Video Streams, where it can be
>   accessed by the integrations that you allow. For example, you could
>   integrate customer voice stream with real-time text transcription and
>   sentiment analysis for immediate feedback on call quality, or use this
>   feature with a 3rd party voice biometric product to authenticate the
>   caller automatically without having to enter a password or confirm
>   personal information.

Comment: Hi don't know java,I can understand only python but I need to deploy architecture in this link:  https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-connect-realtime-transcription please suggest way to deploy, please comment or whatsapp (9949183895) in next 2 days I need to deploy, kindly help

Comment: Hi @bwest as per your comment "the only way to get that real-time data from Amazon Connect is via Kinesis." Then why you believe Transcribe & Kinesis both the services implemented in architecture : https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-connect-realtime-transcription       any Idea? one is enough right !

Comment: Kinesis is the transport mechanism to move data from Connect to Transcribe.

Comment: Got it Thankyou